# How to format a date with specific time zone in Angular?

Tags: angular, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to format the timestamp into a specific format. Please help me to do this using moment.js

required format: 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss':'UTC -5'
this can be UTC -6 as well. I was able to achieve this using Angular date pipe. But now I want this to be done using the moment.js library.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

I would Personally use day.js as Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode.

To your question it is a bit unclear to understand but this is what I got from reading it. This is one of the many approaches you can take. I think you can install moment-timezone `npm install moment-timezone`

and the you can use something like this
`now = moment(new Date());`

`currentDate = this.now.tz("asia_yekaterinburg").format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");`

I have the working example. https://moment-js-timezone.stackblitz.io

Feel free to improve this answer or modify.

**Update using with Moment.js**
In the component
`import moment = require ("moment");`
`now = moment(new Date());`
 `momentDate = moment(this.nowTime).utcOffset(-5).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");`

In the Html

`{{momentDate}}`

Comment: I need with moment only and that too I wanted to know how I can specify UTC -5

Comment: @Deepender updated the answer hope that will resolve your problem'.